# How to prevent autheticated user from sending similar request via POSTMAN?

Tags: validation, authentication, postman, mean-stack, system-design

I am developing a simple website using MEAN stack that gives a logged-in user a task to complete and sends a score to the backend corresponding to their performance on that task. User can skip to next task in which case no score is sent. Problem is: How can I differentiate between a user cheating and sending score via a POST request on POSTMAN (by changing POST values to increase score) and a POST request created by my frontend code. How to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, to check if the request is made by POSTMAN (so locally) or by your backend (called by your front end) you just have to check if the request IP is your server or not.

This is a WhiteList solution

MEAN Stack use NodeJS, so you can use :

```
request.connection.remoteAddress
```

EDIT :

You can put a special parameter in your header when send a request with your front OR your Postman, and you check it when you receive it

Comment: I think there is confusion. I am comparing POST request using POSTMAN from user machine and POST request that my frontend js code generates (not backend!) on user machine when it has to connect to backend and save the score. In this case, both POSTMAN and the frontend requests will have the same remoteAddress.

Comment: I think any static parameter sent from frontend will be visible in chrome dev console. Which the user can copy-paste in POSTMAN for subsequent cheating. How to work around this problem?